# Spring Data Controller with Multiple Datasources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've setup a Spring Data project with two different datasources and am trying to invoke database-specific functions from a single `@Controller`. I have two separate Entity Managers, Connection Properties and Transaction Managers for each datasource.

Below is my current `@Controller`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchDB1", produces="application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Map<String, Object>> getList1() {
         List<Map<String, Object>> list = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
            "select name, id from db1.Database1"
         );
         return list;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchDB2", produces="application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getList2() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
            "select name, id from db2.Database2"
        );
    }
```

This will obviously fail as my jdbcTemplate is only wired to a single database at a time - what might be the best way for my controller to choose between databases depending on which method is called (Abstracting to Service Impl, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing stopping you from depending on two `JdbcTemplate`. You have not shown the rest of the code but you could depend on two data sources and initialize the `JdbcTemplate` when needed as it is an utility class more than a dependable resource.

The most simple way of passing the two data sources is to make it explicit.

```xml
<bean id="myBean" class="my.Controller">
  <property name="dataSource1" ref="ds1"/>
  <property name="dataSource2" ref="ds2"/>
</bean>
```

Nevertheless, you can also use `@Qualifier` as shown in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers).

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
    ...
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ds1")
    private DataSource dataSource1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ds2")
    private DataSource dataSource2;
    ...
}
```